# Why doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I am very new in the node.js and socket.io and when I am trying to run app.js in the console (with node app.js) it just show me "listening on 3000" and when I enter index.html and refresh it in the console doesn't tell me that a user connected [here is my folder``](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPd3Y.png).
Here is app.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
 var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log('listening on *:3000');
 });
```

AND here is the index.htm`

```
     <html>
       <head>
         <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
         <style>
           * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
           body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
           form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
           form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
           form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
           #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
           #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
           #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
         </style>
       </head>
       <body>
         <ul id="messages"></ul>
         <form action="">
           <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
         </form>
       </body>
     </html>
     </html>
</html>`
```

What I want is to write me in the console "a user connected " when I enter the page(or refresh it).

Comment: You need to include [`socket.io.js`](https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js) in your index.html (Client) file.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep reading on the same tutorial which you are following you will come to the part were they include the frontend socket.io library. So just keep reading part "Integrating Socket.IO"

Link: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/